# What is the proper conversion for factors to numeric, when the original factor levels are composed of strings?

Tags: r, string, factors

We have a data frame with factors:

```
df <- data.frame("Var1" = c("A", "B", "B", "C"),
                 "Var2" = c("Can", "Can", "Not", "Not"))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 2 3
 $ Var2: Factor w/ 2 levels "Can","Not": 1 1 2 2
```

Now we need to convert the factors to numeric values

```
dfb <- df
dfb[sapply(dfb, is.factor)] <- lapply(dfb[sapply(dfb, is.factor)], 
                                        as.numeric)

> str(dfb)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: num  1 2 2 3
 $ Var2: num  1 1 2 2

> summary(as.factor(dfb$Var1))
1 2 3 
1 2 1 
> summary(df$Var1)
A B C 
1 2 1
```

The quantity within each level is equivalent. Yet according to the documentation for factor, there is this warning sign:

> In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

If we apply that function to the original data frame we get NAs.

```
df <- data.frame("Var1" = c("A", "B", "B", "C"),
                 "Var2" = c("Can", "Can", "Not", "Not"))

df[sapply(df, is.factor)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.factor)], 
                                       function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])

Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So, is the proper way to convert these factors to numeric simply

```
as.numeric()
```

I am applying this to 18 variables some of which have upwards of 52 levels and I need to ensure that I am converting them correctly to numeric. It seems correct based on my tests but the documentations warning is throwing me off. I believe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: What is your expected output.  if you convert to `character` and then to numeric, then the value should be numeric for that to happen.  If you are interested in the integer storage values, then `as.integer` or `as.numeric` directly works

Comment: The `dfb` you created would be correct if you just wanted conversion to integer storage values i..e ` "A","B","C": 1 2 2 3`  in the first column, 'A', 'B', 'C' are converted to 1, 2, 3

Comment: dfb is what I am looking for. I believe it's working I am just not sure what I am misunderstanding about that snippet within the documentation

Comment: It is actually the correct way.  In the documentation, it also warns, when you are converting a factor vector into numeric  which should be actually numeric.  i.e. `v1 <- factor(c(2, 5, 2, 10, 3))` if you do `as.integer(v1)` it gets a different value, instead here it is `as.numeric(as.character(v1))`

Comment: As an aside, for automatically changing the columns into different types by value, you can use `type.convert`

Comment: Okay I understand it now. Only if they are numeric values encoded as factors will that issue arise, because they won't retain their original values

Comment: I submitted a documentation improvement for this a few weeks ago: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17754 https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/a029bab0553c732b82704706f4835df39e9ab39d